# Interpreting 3 Circled Venn Diagrams

Tags: algebra-precalculus, data-analysis

[image: Image of the problem is shown]

The Venn diagram above represents the 20 students who took one or more of the 3 available art classes or took no art classes at all. two students took no classes at all. 
1.How many people take only two classes?

2. How many elements are there in the intersection of Photography and Sculpture?
   Why is the number of these elements 3 instead of 2?
   If the number of elements were 3, then wouldn't we be including the elements common to painting in addition to photography and sculpture?
3. I have difficulty with venn diagrams in general. Could you give me additional questions that will help me understand venn-diagrams? What are other questions that could be asked to interpret the diagram?

Comment: This Venn Diagram would be slightly easier to comprehend with hatching / shading, I suspect that's what's causing you confusion.

Comment: I suspect that the numbers written on the diagram are not the elements, but the numbers of elements in each set. Therefore you have 2 elements in the intersection of Photography and Sculpture, but not in Painting (lower left part of the diagram), and 1 element in the intersection of the three sets (centre of figure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Venn diagram below.

[image]

The students who take Painting are represented by the red disk (including the regions shown in magenta, white, and yellow).  The students who take Photography are represented by the blue disk (including the regions shown in magenta, white, and cyan). The students who take Sculpture are represented by the green disk (including the regions shown in yellow, white, and cyan).  The students who do not take any of the art courses are represented by the light gray region inside the rectangle but outside the circles.

The students who take more than one course are represented by the regions in which the disks intersect.

1. The students who take exactly two courses are represented by the regions where exactly two of the disks intersect.  There are two students in the magenta region who take Painting and Photography.  There are three students in the yellow region who take Painting and Sculpture.  There are two students in the cyan region who take Photography and Sculpture.  Thus, the number of students taking exactly two of the courses is

$$2 + 3 + 2 = 7$$

2. The three students who take both Photography and Sculpture are represented by the cyan and white regions where the blue and green disks intersect.  The two students who take only Photography and Sculpture are represented by the cyan region.  The one student who also takes Painting is represented by the white region where all three disks intersect.
3. Other questions that could be asked include:

(a) How many students are enrolled in exactly one of the courses?

Answer:  $10$

(b) How many students are enrolled in all three courses?

Answer:  $1$

(c) How many students take both Painting and Photography?

Answer:  $3$

(d) How many students take at least one of the courses Painting and Sculpture?

Answer:  $15$

Comment: Taussig how did you get 10 for the number of students enrolled in exactly one of the courses? How did you calculate the number of students who take at least one of the courses Painting and Sculpture? I don't understand what you mean by one of the c. Paint + sculpture, do you mean, take either painting or sculpture?

Comment: To find the number of students who take exactly one of the courses, look in the three regions (red, blue, green) where the disks do not intersect.  There are three students who take only Painting (the red region), three students who take only Photography (the blue region), and four students who take only Sculpture (the green region), giving a total of $3 + 3 + 4 = 10$ students who take exactly one of the courses.

Comment: By taking at least one of the courses Painting and Sculpture, I meant students who take Painting or Sculpture or both.  You find the answer by adding up the numbers in the two disks representing the students who take Painting or Sculpture, making sure to count each region only once.

Comment: for the part d I tried 3 + 4 + 4, what am I doing wrong? did you count the region twice to get 15?

Comment: When you are counting students who take at least one of the courses Painting and Sculpture, you must account for students who take Painting or Sculpture or both.  Every student in the red and green disks must be counted.  The students who take Painting are represented by the red, magenta, white, and yellow regions.  The students who take Sculpture are represented by the green, cyan, yellow, and white regions.  To find the number of students who take at least one of the courses, we add the students in these regions, which yields $3 + 2 + 1 + 3 + 4 + 2 = 15$.

Comment: Red region: students who take only Painting.  Blue region:  students who take only Photography.  Green region:  students who take only Sculpture.  Magenta region:  students who take Painting and Photography but not Sculpture.  Yellow region:  students who take Painting and Sculpture but not Photography.  Cyan region:  students who take Photography and Sculpture but not painting.  White region:  students who take Painting, Photography, and Sculpture.  Grey region:  students who take neither Painting nor Photography nor Sculpture.

Comment: how many total students are enrolled in painting? 9?

Comment: That is correct.